# Connect to PostgreSQL database using EntityFramework 6 (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create database on PostgreSQL server using Entity Framework Code-First in C# application. I have downloaded Npgsql for EF and tried to change my App.config file in different ways presented on Internet, however none works.

This is my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PostgreSql" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=true;User Id=postgre;Password=password;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I would like to add that `SqlServer` works. I would be grateful for help.

Comment: If you need both providers in your application, you'll need to tell EF which one to use for your context. Otherwise, remove the SqlServer entry and change the default connection factory to be the one provided by Npgsql.

Comment: In Context class constructor I am using base("PostgreSql"). How should default look like?

Comment: That should be enough. Are you getting any errors when using the context?

Comment: @Spivonious yep. "The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details."

Comment: I've changed connection string for "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=password;" and It connects i think. It breaks at ctx.SaveChanges(); with npgsql exception 42601

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was trying a different configurations and options and finally found the solution.

Connection string section should be like:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PostgreSql" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=1234;Database=SchoolDB;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And the providers:

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
</providers>
```

Moreover, at the end of  section I have added the following

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

It creates new database on SQL Server of PostgreSQL depending on how DbContext base class is called.

Comment: This is great, you saved my day. I was struggling with this and your code fixed the issue. thanks for sharing , I also have this this line in my web.config                           <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.6.0" newVersion="3.2.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Happy that it helped you